Muchas personas /mucha gente with nouns
In a recent exam, this translation turned up:
Many people are fans of sport.
Are these both correct?
Muchas personas son aficionadAs del deporte.
And
Mucha gente Es aficionadA del deporte.
My question,in the first example is:
Is the noun,in this case''aficionado/a'' always in agreement with ''personas''as ''personas''is a feminine noun? That is what I think is correct.
Secondly,in the other example,I believe ''gente''is a singular noun always.
Therfore ,am I correct in saying ''la gente ES aficionada del deporte''?
Ok.That sounds strange to me as a native -English speaker where I would say, ''Many people are fans of sport''.
Obviously, this is Spanish so what is correct in both cases?

aficionados al deporte.  Not del. Yes, it agrees with whatever the noun is.

That English is bad. So, as an English speaker, how is it you don't know that? We say sports' fans.

@Lambie. Sorry to contradict you but both versions are correct

@Lambie It’s not sports’ fans either https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sports-fans

@ Lambie: La diferencia entre “aficionados de” y “aficionados a” radica en el uso preposicional y el contexto en el que se emplean:
• Aficionados a: Se utiliza para indicar una inclinación o gusto por una actividad o cosa. Por ejemplo, “aficionados a la música” o “aficionados al fútbol”. Aquí, “a” introduce la actividad o cosa que les gusta.
• Aficionados de: Se usa para referirse a personas que apoyan o siguen a un equipo, grupo o persona. Por ejemplo, “aficionados del Real Madrid” o “aficionados de Shakira”. En este caso, “de” introduce el objeto de su afición.

Muchas personas son aficionadas al deporte:
In this sentence, “personas” is a feminine plural noun, so the adjective “aficionadas” must agree with it in both gender and number. Therefore, “aficionadas” is correct.
Mucha gente es aficionada al deporte:
“Gente” is a singular collective noun, so it takes a singular verb and adjective. Therefore, “es aficionada” is correct.
In Spanish, adjectives must agree in gender and number with the nouns they modify, which can be different from English.

Great! that is what I thought originally.Many thanks

@Bluelion7 CPT Zero says this is AI generated, most likley. We discourage this use here. The point is for people to answer, not machines. This person keeps using Chatgpt and should stop it doing that here.

This answer is clear for everyone and correct , and surely you will never believe that I cannot answer such a simple question myself without looking something up.

Although the word "gente" refers to many people, in Spanish it is singular and feminine word, so you have to consider that when you use and adjective.
Related to this, that is why many Spanish speakers make this mistake with this example in English:

People is crazy, which is wrong, instead of the correct way People are
crazy


Please check your grammar.

@Lambie If I want to use aficionado as a noun, not an adjective, would it be "muchas personas son aficionados" or "muchas personas son aficionadas"?

@Bluelion7 The RAE says it's an adjective only, not a noun. ser aficionado a x. So muchas personas son aficionadas.

Adjetivo y sustantivo (II). Adjetivos sustantivados | Nueva gramática de la lengua española | RAE - ASALE 13.7d: Destacan entre todos estos adjetivos de persona convertidos en sustantivos los que caracterizan los siguientes aspectos de los individuos: … Aspectos del carácter o la personalidad: una aficionada, un beato, un fresco, un informal, una optimista, un pecador, una santa, un tacaño, un vivo.
